# How do I condition a string variable from a random generator based on the results of another random variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to javascript coding and wanted to run a simple command for filling in a table using the math.random function. I want to constrain one random variable based on the output of another random variable. I created a function, which I was hoping would condition the new random variable from a prior random variable based on a specific output. Any help would be appreciated.

Below is the the javascript code (I'm just trying to condition educational background based on earlier draw of occupation):

```
// generate string variables
var vjob = ["Retail worker", "Financial analyst"];
var vedu1 = ["Secondary", "Bachelor's", "Masters or professional degree"];
var vedu2 = ["Bachelor's", "Masters or professional degree"];

// random generator fn conditional on occupational outcome 
function getEDU() {
    var rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * vjob.length);
    var rand2 = vedu1[Math.floor(Math.random() * vedu1.length)];
    var rand3 = vedu2[Math.floor(Math.random() * vedu2.length)];

    if (rand1 == "Financial Analyst") {
        return rand1;
    }
    return rand2;
}


// Use math.random to randomly select traits for each dimension for Person A & Person B
traits_a = [vjob[Math.floor(Math.random() * vjob.length)],
            getEDU()];

traits_b = [vjob[Math.floor(Math.random() * vjob.length)],
            getEDU()];        

// Create list of variables to use when setting attributes
a_list = ["a1", "a2"];
b_list = ["b1", "b2"];

// set html values in conjoint table
for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    document.getElementById(a_list[i]).innerHTML = traits_a[i];
    document.getElementById(b_list[i]).innerHTML = traits_b[i];
}
```

I pass that through onto a table in html:

```
<table border="1px solid black" cellpadding="15" cellspacing="2" width="90%">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td style="font-weight:bold; font-size:1.25em; font-align:center;">Person A</td>
   <td style="font-weight:bold; font-size:1.25em; font-align:center;">Person B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td style="font-weight:bold;">Occupation</td>
   <td id="a1"></td>
   <td id="b1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td style="font-weight:bold;">Level of education</td>
   <td id="a2"></td>
   <td id="b2"></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```